# Swift compiler error while using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

I get this compile error:

```
   Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

with this function:

```
   func saveChanges()->Bool {
    var path = self.itemArchivePath()
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.someArray, toFile: path)
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I see `Xcode6-Beta.app` in the path to `swift`, which is the very first beta apple released. You should definitely upgrade to the lates version. (As of today that is Beta 2)

Comment: Do you get a more specific error from the compiler or does it just crash during compilation? (See my previous comment)

Answer (score -2):

It is because NSKeyedArchiver need an NSArray instead of NSMutableArray

```
func saveChanges()->Bool {
    var path = self.itemArchivePath()
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.someArray as NSArray, toFile: path)
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that makes sense since an `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`.